# Running latex (pdf) interactively in AucTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, terminal-output

When I am Running latex interactively, as I like, emacs is opening a new buffer-window with output from the LaTeX compiling process. Fine! -- I like to see the processing outut. BUT I am used to that this buffer (window) always view the last line of the process output. Is there a `.emacs` "trick" for this to happen?

Best Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm having trouble understanding what you want to do, here.  Can you rephrase, or perhaps an example of what you'd like to see?

Comment: Is this what is happening: run `latex` with `C-c C-c`, and AUCTeX split the (active) buffer and open `*<filename> output*` in a buffer?  This does not happen by default in my setup.  And if I open that `*output*` buffer with `C-c C-l`, it does automatically open at the end of that 'file'.  Do you have some non-default settings in your `.emacs`?

Comment: @jon I suppose he set `TeX-show-compilation` to `t`.

Comment: Wrong guess: `TeX-interactive-mode` shows the compilation buffer without touching `TeX-show-compilation`.

Comment: @giordano -- Well that makes sense.  My non-solution would be to not turn on that setting: but I run `latex` far to often to want that buffer to show automatically.  (I probably need more discipline with the 'focus on the writing' mentality...)

Comment: Thank for help. -- Adding (setq TeX-show-compilation t) to my .emacs file did the job! :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering to remove this question from the unanswered queue.

You should set [`TeX-show-compilation`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dshow_002dcompilation) to `t`.  You can do that by adding the following code to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq TeX-show-compilation t)
```